# Golang : converting yyyy:MM:dd hr:mm:ss i.e I am getting date in string and the same date need to be parse to save in mysql db

Tags: go

```
layout := "2006-01-02 15:04:05"
    str := "2018-10-11 13:10:47"
    t, err := time.Parse(layout, str)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(t)
```

> I am getting output as 2018-10-11 13:10:47 +0000 UTC, but I want to
>   store in mysql db as 2018-10-11 13:10:47. How do I parse exactly for
>   mysql datetime?

Answer (score 7):

```
layout := "2006-01-02 15:04:05"
fmt.Println(t.Format(layout))
```

Output:

```
2018-10-11 13:10:47
```

---

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    layout := "2006-01-02 15:04:05"
    str := "2018-10-11 13:10:47"
    t, err := time.Parse(layout, str)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(t)
    fmt.Println(t.Format(layout))
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/NuloBCXBdhH

Output:

```
2018-10-11 13:10:47 +0000 UTC
2018-10-11 13:10:47
```

Answer (score 1):

How about useing `DateFormatToLayout("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")` utility method to convert ISO date style to time layout

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/viant/toolbox"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    timeLayout := toolbox.DateFormatToLayout("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", time.Now().Format(timeLayout))
}
```

[Time Utils](https://github.com/viant/toolbox/#time-utilities)

Comment: Thank you  Adrian this is the most generic answer

Comment: Hi Adrian the output is type string instead of mysq tiime/time.time. I am extracting string date from .csv & storing in mysql datetime.

Comment: just convert you text time repesentation to time.Time, with time.Parse(timeLayout, csvTextTime)